# Dirty CoW mitigation on CentOS 7.2 - semantic error: while resolving probe point

Tags: linux, system-calls, centos7, rhel7, dirtyread

I am working on implementing a temp patch (non-persistent) on my system as described here (while waiting for the official distro kernel):

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1384344#c13

I have tested a dirty copy on write script for the intent of testing the resolution of this bug on my system but note that I am getting a semantic error and that this bug is still active on my system:

```
SuperUser Shell ~/> # stap -g -p 4 fix.stp 
semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'syscall' at fix.stp:5:7
        source: probe syscall.ptrace {  // includes compat ptrace as well
                      ^

semantic error: no match

Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]
SuperUser Shell ~/>
```

With color (if that's your thing):

[image]

Reading this article:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/errors.html

I see a brief explanation:

> **semantic error: no match for probe point, while resolving probe point `foo`**
>   The events / handler function foo could not be resolved
>   altogether, for a variety of reasons. This error occurs when the
>   script contains the event kernel.function("blah"), and blah does not
>   exist. In some cases, the error could also mean the script contains an
>   invalid kernel file name or source line number.

### Questions:

- This is essentially stating that the `syscall` kernel function is not recognized, correct?
- Has anyone successfully implemented this temp fix on CentOS 7.x yet?

**Thanks for any help**

PS: Sorry if this seems somewhat script kiddy-ish (I don't fully understand this hot fix yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I have successfully implemented this temporary mitigation on CentOS 7.

As described in one of the [comments](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1384344#c32) on that bugzilla entry, you need to install the both systemtap and the debuginfo for the kernel in order for this mitigation to work.

The commands given are:

```
yum install systemtap yum-utils
debuginfo-install kernel-$(uname -r)
```

Based on what you posted, presumably you already have systemtap, but the error you're getting suggests you need the debuginfo packages. The second command above should install the right stuff; you could also get the RPMs by hand from http://debuginfo.centos.org/ (this is what I ended up doing)

By the way, this mitigation using systemtap is not a real fix, it just makes one of the proof of concept programs fail. It is worth doing, but no substitute for a real patched kernel.

I don't understand why Red Hat and CentOS haven't pushed out patched kernel packages yet, Ubuntu and others had their updates out days ago. What's the holdup?

Comment: Awesome I tested this on my system as well and can verify that this is correct.  Thank you for your time! https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1384344#c13 with packages described above and in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1384344#c32